# Images.xcassets: How to use one image for all resolutions

Tags: ios, xcasset

I'm trying to use a PDF scalar vector image instead of having 1x,2x,3x image sizes.
However, when I drag my PDF image it create three slots when I only want one "All".

Looks like this:
[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

How to configure the image so there's only one slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell it that this was a vector image:

[image]